# How to get CheckBoxFor value from table in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have to get checked checkboxes from table column. I have done this to achieve the require result but couldn't find the exact solution and return null value in http post.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Users.ToList());
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index( List<User> user) 
    {
        return View(db.Users.ToList());
    }
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<EntityframeworkDemo.User>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<table class="table">
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.C_Password)</td>
        <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Validations.Value)</td>
    </tr> }
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Post" />
}
```

Model Class:

```
Class User
{
        public int U_id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string C_Password { get; set; }
        public bool? Validations { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please Provide Any Sample

Comment: Do you have a reason for making the Validations bool nullable?

Comment: I m Using Validations Admin Active and Inactive Users

Comment: If you want to use it for three states for a nullable bool, then check out the link @OrelEraki posted. I'd suggest an enum with Admin, Active, and Inactive to more clearly model your values.

Comment: I cannot Understand This Link Please You Apply My Code

Comment: Not only can you not use a `foreach` loop (refer the dupe), You cannot bind a `bool?` to a checkbox - a nullable `bool` has 3 states, but a checkbox has only 2 states. You need `EditorFor()` which will generate a `<select>` with 2 values for `null`, `true` and `false`. And would also need an additional form control for the ID so you can match up your items.

Comment: I've tried all these but HttpPost method still getting null value

Comment: Then you did not try correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you handle Nullable boolean on Data Tier and when it comes to ViewModel make it regular boolean then your code should work

public bool Validations { get; set; } instead of

public bool? Validations { get; set; }

and

@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Validations)

instead of

@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Validations.Value)

On data tier check if your row is returning null and make it false when it does